# Need to convert cstring to byte* and need to pass it as an i/p argument in c++ functions

Tags: c++, c

In SendCompressedString(),

*passing the compressed data string as an i/p argument.

*Tried printing the whole compressed data in a console window.Can able to print it in the console window....

*Now i need to convert that whole data to Byte * and sizeof that data as an i/p argument to SendBytes()

```
    bool NetOutputBuffer_c::SendCompressedString ( std::string sStr )
    {
                std::cout.write(sStr.c_str(), sStr.size()); 
                SendInt ( sStr.size() );                
                return SendBytes ( sStr.c_str(), sStr.size() ); 
    }
```

In SendBytes(),

- Tried to print the pBuf data but can able to print only 5% of data...
- what shall i need to do inorder to print the whole data?

  bool NetOutputBuffer_c::SendBytes ( const void * pBuf, int iLen )
  {
              BYTE * pMy = (BYTE*)pBuf;
              printf("pMy is %s\n",pMy);

  ```
          while ( iLen>0 && !m_bError )
          {
                  int iLeft = m_iBufferSize - ( m_pBufferPtr-m_pBuffer );
                  printf("iLeft is %d\n",iLeft);
                  if ( iLen<=iLeft )
                  {
                          printf("iLen is %d\n",iLen);
                          memcpy ( m_pBufferPtr, pMy, iLen );
                          printf("m_pBuffer is %s\n",(char*)m_pBufferPtr);
                          m_pBufferPtr += iLen;
                          break;
                  }

                  ResizeIf ( iLen );
          }
          return !m_bError;
  }
  ```

Requirement::

In SendCompressedString(),

*Need to convert the whole data into Byte * and send it as an i/p argument to SendBytes()

*In SendBytes(),need to print all the data...

*Can someone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: `memcpy` in `while..loop` wrong. You can do like `if(iLen>0){memcpy ( m_pBufferPtr, pMy, iLen );}`. No need to while loop.

Comment: Actually my question was not related to memcpy so i have not copied the whole code....For ur verification,i have posted the whole code

Comment: Actually your question edited after my comment.Don't edit to hide previous bug and raise new question.If you not know then Don't argue  again any one's useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing the memcpy in a loop? That looks wrong to me. Here is the memcpy reference:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

So you just need to specify a source and destination pointer (address) and what size to copy. So your code should be:

```
bool NetOutputBuffer_c::SendBytes ( const void * pBuf, int iLen )
{
    BYTE * pMy = (BYTE*)pBuf;
    memcpy ( m_pBufferPtr, pMy, iLen );
}
```

Comment: Remember to ensure that `iLen > 0` as in Jayesh's comment.

Comment: From the C99 standard (7.21.1/2):
Where an argument declared as size_t n specifies the length of the array for a function, n can have the value zero on a call to that function. Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4. On such a call, a function that locates a character finds no occurrence, a function that compares two character sequences returns zero, and a function that copies characters copies zero characters.

Comment: So the 0 check is unnecessary. And yes, I do not like doing what's already been done for me :).

Comment: Ah, I see. In which case should 'we' not check that `iLen >= 0`? It is concievable that _someone_ could call the function with a negative `iLen`

Comment: Baldrickk::Tried wat u said...When i tried to print the pMy value,can able to print only 5% of data (not the whole data.)